# Javascript: is package.json dependency included in build, if it's not imported anywhere?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, dependency-graph

In project, there is some dependency package (npm install [some-name] --save) listed in package.json file, but not imported in any of my ES6 module files in source code. Will this package be included in final build (ex. rollup output)?

As far as I understand, not imported es6 module can't even provide any side effects, so bundler (ex. rollup, webpack) doesn't have it in dependency graph. And because of this, bundler doesn't even know about its existence. So, if I'am correct, such package is not included in bundle. But, in such case, what's the reason for separating "dependencies" and "dev-dependencies" in package.json, for projects that use any bundler, if bundler decides with its own logic (when it follows "import/export" statements) what to include in output?

Comment: The package.json and the dev-dependencies are primarily about your module being installed by others, when you do not distribute a bundled version with all dependencies included.

Answer (score 2):

According to `Webpack` doc, Webpack generates a [dependency graph](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/) starting from [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/under-the-hood/) which is usually `index.js`.
And also if you use something like `create-react-app` that uses webpack under the hood, it will generate a package json like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
  },
```

You can see there is no `devDependencies`! that means not all thing that you just put on the `dependencies` will be included in your final build.

Finally I've tested inside a new `CRA` my app:

1. pressed `npm run build` on the bare installed:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

2. Installed axios via `npm i axios`, but never imported it.
   output after running `npm run build`:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

Nothin has been changed!

3. import axios from "axios", inside but never use it in the code:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the output:

```
[eslint]
src\App.js
  Line 3:8:  'axios' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

Again nothing changed! but you can see `eslint` warning too!

4. Use one of it's functions e.g. get method only:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  console.log(axios.get);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

the output:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  57.92 kB (+11.31 kB)  build\static\js\main.4c83ea39.js
  1.78 kB               build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B                 build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

**Conclusion**:

If we don't use a package inside our app, it won't get into the final build.

**Note:**

Although extra packages won't affect production, don't forget to uninstall unused packages from time to time.
Running npm install still install every package defined in the package.json, no matter whether they are used or not. So having loads of unused packages will slow down deployment and affect your teammates (they need to run npm install as well!!.

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/111hbws/are_all_dependencies_ins_packagejson_will_be/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right the bundler won't include it when you bundle. The code is dead-code which should be removed.

But I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that when your consumers of a library do `npm install` they will have to download everything inside `package.json` to resolve its dependencies. At least that's my reasoning.

Comment: _(correct me if I'm wrong) that when your consumers of a library do npm install they will have to download everything inside_ - You're right. But as far as I know, all those packages increase project size in computer file system of a certain developer, but NOT the size of a build file. But i'm not sure, and that's why I'm asking :) Of course it's not a good pattern to keep unused packages in package.json or keep dev-dependencies on "dependencies" list, but my concern is, if it's TECHNICALLY wrong for result js application, despite the fact it's messy during development.

Comment: @Maciej it's JS, there are many technically wrong things in it 