# Do non-imported files get included in the build size in React Native?

Tags: react-native, build, apk

I have a large file in the root directory of my project. I use it only during development, and before building the application, I remove the imports and usage of that file from the application. However, the file still exists in my root directory. Will it be included in my build and increase the size?

I tried generating the build both with and without importing the file. The size increases when I add an import statement and doesn't increase in size when I remove the import. I still want to confirm this behavior. Could you please help and share the documentation or article where this behavior is explained?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from another answer I found in stackoverflow for React, but I think it should be the same case as React Native:

> If we don't use (import) a package inside our app, it won't get into the final build.

See how the bundle file size changes for few scenarios in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75445347/5357454) ;
The answer is actually taken from this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/111hbws/are_all_dependencies_ins_packagejson_will_be/)

I pasted them here for easiness:

According to `Webpack` doc, Webpack generates a [dependency graph](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/) starting from [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/under-the-hood/) which is usually `index.js`.
And also if you use something like `create-react-app` that uses webpack under the hood, it will generate a package json like this:

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
  },
```

You can see there is no `devDependencies`! that means not all thing that you just put on the `dependencies` will be included in your final build.

Finally I've tested inside a new `CRA` my app:

1. pressed `npm run build` on the bare installed:

```js
File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

2. Installed axios via `npm i axios`, but never imported it.
   output after running `npm run build`:

```js
File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

Nothin has been changed!

3. import axios from "axios", inside but never use it in the code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the output:

```js
[eslint]
src\App.js
  Line 3:8:  'axios' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.46f5c8f5.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

Again nothing changed! but you can see `eslint` warning too!

4. Use one of it's functions e.g. get method only:

```js
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  console.log(axios.get);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

the output:

```js
File sizes after gzip:

  57.92 kB (+11.31 kB)  build\static\js\main.4c83ea39.js
  1.78 kB               build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B                 build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
```

**Conclusion**:

If we don't use a package inside our app, it won't get into the final build.

**Note:**

Although extra packages won't affect production, don't forget to uninstall unused packages from time to time.
Running npm install still install every package defined in the package.json, no matter whether they are used or not. So having loads of unused packages will slow down deployment and affect your teammates (they need to run npm install as well!!.

Answer (score 0):

The files that are not imported anywhere in the project will not be included in the build size.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by providing a link to documentation or other source which can verify what's being said here.